# Django: How to remove a coupon from an order without deleting coupon from database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Hey guys I have this coupon model, I need to give it a remove functionality (not delete from database), to remove coupon from the order if the customer wishes to. How can I have that functionality? If I use delete(), it will delete the coupon from database, and using remove() shows an attribute error.

model:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
amount = models.FloatField(max_length=4)
valid_from = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
valid_to = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
max_value = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)], verbose_name='Coupon Quantity', null=True)
used = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unset relation on foreign key

```
order.coupon = None
order.save()
```

Comment: you didn't save changes afterwards

Comment: Thank you for the answer..but the coupon.used is not getting decremented. How can I do that also?

Comment: coupon.save() after you decrement it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Oh..yes, sorry! my bad! I forgot about that.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: also check following https://riptutorial.com/django/example/9302/avoiding-race-conditions

Comment: Yes. Thanks! thats something important!